# Context menu on any control on form

Tags: wpf, vb.net

How would i display a context menu with a button in it by right-clicking on any element on form?

The purpose of a button in a form would be:

Displaying a x:Name of a control on which a right click(displaying a context menu )is performed.

To summarize, i want to right click on any element on form to display context menu with 1 button "Show me name" which should show messagebox displaying: "My name is [x:name of element]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an implicit `Style` for each type of control:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="cm">
            <MenuItem Header="Show name" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
        </ContextMenu>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="a" Content="a" />
        <TextBox x:Name="b" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem mi = sender as MenuItem;
    ContextMenu cm = mi.Parent as ContextMenu;
    FrameworkElement fe = cm.PlacementTarget as FrameworkElement;
    MessageBox.Show(fe.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, exactly what i needed!